# Declare get accessors in PowerShell cmdlet parameters

Tags: c#, powershell, properties, parameters, pipeline

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> "Parameters must be declared on public non-static fields or
>   properties. Parameters should be declared on properties. The property
>   must have a public set accessor, and if the ValueFromPipeline or
>   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName keyword is specified, the property
>   must have a public get accessor."

Why do I have to declare get accessors in my cmdlet `ValueFromPipeline` parameters? As far as I know, PowerShell only needs to put their values in, not read them out. Thanks (by the way im just curious about this behavior :) ).

Comment: It does seem an odd requirement. I can only assume it is an implementation artefact (ie. leaky abstraction): following through code when dealing with validations and type conversions applied to parameter properties shows the processing is not simple. On the other hand I've rarely used anything other than an automatic property with public set and get and cannot think of a circumstance where I would want anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell **reads the default value** of the parameters marked with `ValueFromPipeline` or `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` to make a backup *before* assigning the new value obtained from [the pipeline](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2008/11/23/chapter-5-the-powershell-pipeline.aspx).

Consider the following cmdlets:

```
New-Post -Title <string>
Set-Post -InputObject <Post> -Title <string>
```

where the following applies:

- the `New-Post` cmdlet *returns* the newly created `Post` object to the pipeline, which *has* a `Title` property
- the `InputObject` property on the `Set-Post` cmdlet is marked with `ValueFromPipeline = true`
- the `Title` property on the `Set-Post` cmdlet is marked with `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true`.

Combining them with the following command:

```
New-Post -Title "Foo" | Set-Post
```

and setting a breakpoint on the get accessor of the `Set-Post` cmdlet's `Title` property results in the following stack trace:

[image: Stack trace for parameter binding in PowerShell]

As you can see, the `CmdletParameterBinderController.GetDefaultParameterValue` method is invoked during the process of binding the `Title` property on the `Set-Post`cmdlet with the value from the corresponding property on the object coming from the pipeline.

Comment: -1. While there is a logic to this, it isn't how PSH works. Within the cmdlet you call `WriteObject` to pass objects (or collections) to the next step of the pipeline.

Comment: @Richard I think you misunderstood my point. I'm not talking about stopping the entire object from being passed through the pipeline but rather the *automatic assignment of parameters* with the same name. PowerShell wouldn't be able to retrieve the value assigned to the parameters of a cmdlet if the corresponding properties were *write-only*.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio I definitely don't understand now. Why would that require PSH to read the properties value? ByPropertyName requires matching property *name* of object on pipeline to cmdlet property *name*. And obviously name matching must take place before the cmdlet property is assigned, and even then PSH still has the pipeline object from which to read the property value. Finally that still have anything to do with passing objects onwards on the pipe (cmdlet must call `Cmdlet.WriteObject`).

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio The problem here starts with your assertion "must also be able to pass their value on to the next object in the pipeline": this is not true. The object passed onwards, out of a cmdlet has no relation to the input pipeline object: they are completely different (except in the case where the cmdlet explicitly passes the same object to `WriteObject`).

Comment: confused now, but i tend to agree with richard more. according to my knowledge, parameters arent passed to the pipeline like enrico says, but by writeobject.

Comment: @Richard Indeed I was wrong. I updated my answer with the real explanation ;)

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio: Down vote remove. I can't think why PSH would want to backup the value in these cases... maybe there is some back off an retry if the first round of param binding failed? But I would have thought keeping a dictionary {ParameterInfo,Value} would be easier. Summary: I accept why it is doing, but I can't see a rationalisation.